# Get values from a HashSet<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, hashset

I need a way to get the values from a generic HashSet using **reflection**. Here is what I've tried (you can copy/paste this on a console app):

```
 class Program
    {
        public class Order
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person();
            person.Name = "Test Person";

            person.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();

            person.Orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 1 });
            person.Orders.Add(new Order() { Id = 2 });

            var reflectedOrders = person.GetType().GetProperty("Orders").GetValue(person, null);

            Console.WriteLine("How do I iterate the reflected orders?");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

---

### EDIT

It's an example, in the real application I don't know which type to convert the reflected Orders. I only know the property is an `ICollection<T>` (turned to HashShet by EF)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried casting `reflectedOrders` to `IEnumerable`?

```
IEnumerable reflectedOrders = (IEnumerable)person.GetType().GetProperty("Orders").GetValue(person, null);
```

Comment: You can even cast it to the appropriate type directly, or use the _as_ keyword and check for a null reference instead of getting an InvalidCastException if the object is not what you expect

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple as casting:

```
var reflectedOrders = (HashSet<Order>) person.GetType().GetProperty("Orders").GetValue(person, null);

foreach (var order in reflectedOrders)
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the limitation: I don't know that type (the example is just very simplified)

Comment: @ChuckNorris, if you don't care about the type so simply cast to `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var orders = persons.OfType<Person>().SelectMany(p => p.Orders);
```

Comment: Hm, or did I completely misunderstand the question here?

Comment: jaja, yes, I need to use reflection, the example is pretty basic so you can run it directly in a console to test. In fact, @Daniel and @gdoron answered it right. `IEnumerable` is the cast I needed.